# How to show product custom image attribute on detail page in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, image

I have created custom image attribute for the product. Now I want to show this image below the product price on the detail page.

Answer (score 1):

You can call custom image attribute where you want like below:

```
<?php
$productImageAttr = $_product->getCustomAttribute( 'attribute_code' );
if($productImageAttr){
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
    ->init($_product, 'attribute_code')
    ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());
?>
<img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl() ?>" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getTitle()) ?>" />
```